# PreApplicationStartMethod cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, unity-container

I'm trying to use [Unity.Webforms](https://bitbucket.org/KyleK/unity.webforms) in a web application without success. As per the documentation, I put the following line in the AssemblyInfo.cs to tell the runtime to invoke a method before the application starts:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Unity.WebForms.PreApplicationStart), "PreStart")]
```

The error I'm getting says:

> The method specified by the PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute on assembly ... cannot be resolved

And this is the class holding the method (within App_Start folder):

```
using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;

namespace Unity.WebForms
{
    public static class PreApplicationStart
    {
        private static bool _isStarting;

        public static void PreStart()
        {
            if (!_isStarting)
            {
                _isStarting = true;
                DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityHttpModule));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing or misunderstanding?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Unity.Webforms namespace in your custom file with PreApplicationStart, because this namespace already exists.

My solution, that works:

```
using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

namespace TestApp.WebUi
{
    public static class PreApplicationStart
    {
        private static bool _isStarting;

        public static void PreStart()
        {
            if (!_isStarting)
            {
                _isStarting = true;
                DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityHttpModule));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(TestApp.WebUi.PreApplicationStart), "PreStart")]
```